# I can't find this IC marked 54b8

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, integrated-circuit, identification

What are the IC with the marking "54b8" in the photo?

[image: 54b8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [Top Power (拓微集成电) TP4054](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809261814_TOPPOWER-Nanjing-Extension-Microelectronics-TP4054-42-SOT25R_C32574.pdf) Li-Ion charger.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Battery-Management-ICs_TOPPOWER-Nanjing-Extension-Microelectronics-TP4054-42-SOT25R_C32574.html))

Comment: Thank you very much @nanash1